# How can I dynamically add room names to a string array (or anything else that may be easier)?

Tags: c

Basically, the below is part of a program I am using to go through a room game. The key part of my question is after "If(stepCounter!=0)". I am simply looking to add a char string (which will be the name of the room) to an array, named "arrayTracker". After the program is done, it will go through the list and print out all the rooms visited (see part after "if(endFileFound(fileName))").

However, instead of doing this, it is simply printing out the end room for however many lines I have gone through the rooms (so, if I went to four rooms, it prints the end room 3 times and gibberish the first time).

Can someone please explain to me in the simplest way how to simply make something that can allow me to dynamically allocate words to a array and then print them out? This is a lot simpler in higher level languages. Clearly I am not understanding something here. Also, googling appears to lead to things that I am not honestly understanding. Anyways, thanks for any help.

This is the code:

```
//Score Information.
int stepCounter;
//char* array here
stepCounter=0;
char* arrayTracker[100];
        do
        {
                //find the start File and assign it to fileName
                fileName=startPrompt(userInput, roomCode, origRoomTemp);
                printf("%s\n\n", fileName);
                //Print out this if same room is searched or if room was mispelled
                if(strcmp(fileName, origRoomTemp)==0)
                {
                        printf("\n\nHUH, I DON'T UNDERSTAND THAT ROOM. TRY AGAIN \n\n");
                        stepCounter--;
                }
                else
                {
                        if(stepCounter!=0)
                        {
                                stepcounter--;
                                strcpy(arrayTracker[stepCounter],userInput);
                                stepcounter++;
                        }
                }

                //Check the see if end file was reached
                if(endFileFound(fileName))
                {
                        printf("YOU HAVE FOUND THE END ROOM. CONGRADULATIONS!\n");
                        printf("YOU TOOK %d STEPS. YOUR PATH TO VICTORY WAS:\n", stepCounter);
                        int q;
                        for(q=0;q<stepCounter;q++)
                        {
                                printf("%s\n", arrayTracker[q]);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                //stores the term from search
                origRoomTemp=fileName;
                promptInput(fileName);
                scanf("%s", userInput);
                //prevents game from resetting to beginning room.
                roomCode++;
                stepCounter++;

        }
        while(1);
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory for each of the `arrayTracker` pointers, e.g. with `malloc`. Or use `strdup` which does the allocation and copy for you: `arrayTracker[stepCounter] = strdup(userInput)`.

Comment: With that, could I set up my array like this, without allocating a size? AKA, char* arrayTracker[]?

Then use arrayTracker[stepCounter] = strdup(userInput) in the thread to make entries?

Also, would I need to call free(arrayTracker) after with this?

Comment: No. That won't even compile. The size of the array is the max number of words. Then you need another size which is the length of a word for each array entry `malloc` (`strdup` doesn't need the size as it will work it out from the `strlen`). And yes, need to call `free` when done.

Comment: So, then do arrayTracker[100], if I feel that will be the max size of the words in the array?

THEN, put arrayTracker[stepCounter]= strdup(userInput) in the code itself to add to it? Just making sure I'm not missing anything else.

Comment: Yes that'll do it.

Comment: Well, nobody can say it's not indented enough....